# php artisan clear-compiled PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, circleci-2.0

My application's tests are run on circleci for pull requests.  The tests are failing during my composer install command.  It fails once it gets to php artisan clear-compiled, which is run once composer install completes.

config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
   docker:
    - image: circleci/php:7.1-fpm

working_directory: ~/repo

steps:
  - checkout

  # php ini settings
  - run:
      name: Configure Timezone
      command: echo -e "[Date]\ndate.timezone = America/Detroit" | sudo tee /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini > /dev/null
  - run:
      name: Configure Memory Limit
      command: echo -e "memory_limit = 512M" | sudo tee /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini > /dev/null
  - run:
      name: Install mysql php
      command: sudo apt-get install php7.1-fpm

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
      - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
      - v1-dependencies-

  - run: composer install

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ./vendor
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}

  - run: sh tests/unit/runTests.sh
```

The error is PDOException could not find driver.  I'm not sure if there is a better image to choose, but I have also tried to add a few different commands to install php mysql, but those haven't been working.  For example, the latest command I tried was sudo apt-get install php7.1-fpm.  That particular command says unable to locate package.

Comment: Do `sudo apt-cache search php | grep mysql` to find the right package

Comment: I added that command to circle and it exited with code 1 and is not showing the results.  I used the command on a server and a couple of the packages are php-mysql and php7.1-mysql.  I tried both sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql and sudo apt-get install php-mysql.  Both says that it can't find the package.